# If class A has a field B, is there still a way to abstract out A and B

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have a class

```
public class StudentProfile
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string ContactAddress {get; set;}
    public DateTime CreatedDate{get; set;}
    public double PredictedIQScore {get; set;}
    public double PredictedEQScore {get; set;}
    public double Param1 {get; set;}
    public double Param2 {get; set;}
    public double Param3 {get; set;}    
    ...
    public double Param20 {get; set;}    

}
```

I have another class, StudentProfileEvaluation which is constructed with reference to a StudentProfile. There are different evaluation methods that will calculate the student's IQ and EQ based on the StudentProfile's param values.

The purpose of this class, StudentProfileEvaluation is to store those information.

```
public class StudentProfileEvaluation
{
    public StudentProfileEvaluation(StudentProfile studentProfile)
    {
        ParentStudentProfile = studentProfile;
    }

    public readonly ParentStudentProfile;

    private double? predictedIQScore;
    private double? predictedEQScore;

    public double PredictedIQScore
    {
        get 
        {
            if (predictedIQScore.HasValue)
                return predictedIQScore;
            else
                return ParentStudentProfile.PredictedIQScore;
        }
        set
        {
            predictedIQScore = value;
        }
    }

    public double PredictedEQScore
    {
        get 
        {
            if (predictedEQScore.HasValue)
                return predictedEQScore;
            else
                return ParentStudentProfile.PredictedEQScore;
        }
        set
        {
            predictedEQScore = value;
        }
    }
    public double Param1
    {
        return ParentStudentProfile.Param1;
    }
    ...
    public double Param20
    {
        return ParentStudentProfile.Param20;
    }
}
```

Now, throughout the codebase, there are various cases where I want to fetch,

x.PredictedEQScore,
x.PredictedIQScore,
x.param1, x.param2, .............etc to create various graphs and reports. And x can be StudentProfile or StudentProfileEvaluation.

In current setup, I have to do something like the following for every time I generate new graph/report.

```
public void GenerateReport1(StudentProfile studentProfile)
{
    return studentProfile.PredictedEQScore.ToString() +       studentProfile.Param1.ToString() +........
}
public void GenerateReport1(StudentProfileEvaluation studentProfile)
{
   return studentProfile.PredictedEQScore.ToString() + studentProfile.Param1.ToString() +........

}
```

So, although StudentProfile and StudentProfileEvaluation has a "has-a" relationship, I'd like to abstract them out to "is-a" relationship for reporting purposes.

What's a good oop design to establish this?

Answer (score 7):

Inheritance is used to model an "is-a" relationship. So, ask yourself: is a student profile evaluation a kind of student profile? It doesn't sound like it. It sounds like a student profile evaluation *has-a* student profile.

---

To elaborate a little:

*Class A **is-a** B* means that every instance of class A is also an instance of class B. It means that everything you can do with a B, you can also do with an A Can you do everything to a student profile evaluation that you can do with a student profile?

Ask yourself how you would describe the relationship between the classes (or, more accurately, their instances), in a natural language discussion. Perhaps you might say,

> A Student Profile Evaluation holds the results of evaluating a Student Profile

If that is the case, then clearly a student profile evaluation is not a kind of student profile. Among other things, that would mean that a student profile evaluation could hold the results of evaluating a student profile evaluation!

---

Based on your question edit showing the reporting, I would recommend overriding the `ToString()` method in both classes. You could then simply use `studentProfile.ToString()` and `studentProfileEvaluation.ToString()`. "Student Profile Evaluation *is-a* object", and "Student Profile *is-a* object".

Comment: That idea, the *is-a* vs *has-a* should be the first thing taught in any object oriented language regarding inheritance.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Thats the first thing I was taught when learning OOP concepts... Guess they did something right :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET then you had a great instructor.  Sometimes instructors get wrapped up in the how instead of the why.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare *fields* in an interface, but you can declare *properties*, and you have those.

In your case, I might recommend having an interface, or maybe an abstract base class as the progenitor, and have the `StudentProfile` and `StudentProfileEvaluations` implement / inherit that.

That way, `StudentProfile` and `StudentProfileEvaluations` will not (and should not) inherit from one another, and `StudentProfileEvaluations` can have a property that is a `StudentProfile`, even with the constructor you specified.

And the reporting code can be

```
public void GenerateReport(IStudentProfile studentProfile)
{
    return studentProfile.PredictedEQScore.ToString() + studentProfile.Param1.ToString() +........
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you recommended this?

Comment: @JohnSaunders based on the properties shown, they seem pretty similar. Basically, the `Evaluation` will channel it's inner `Profile` property. The `has-a` relationship still holds.

Comment: Ok, but the "purpose" of an interface or abstract class is to group common behaviors. Just because they may have similar properties doesn't mean that they will be treated similarly (except maybe in terms of a report).

Comment: @JohnSaunders, the *x where x is Profile or Evaluation* part, screams common behavior (especially after the edit)

Comment: the common behavior is called `ToString()`.

Comment: I'd disagree. OP mentioned *various graphs and reports*. If he only needs `ToString` then yes, an overload will get the job done. If he needs more, I'd go with an interface.